# Play video from assets in VideoView in Android on API level <7?

Tags: android, video

I want to play a video that is stored in the assets folder of my Android application. The following code works (meaning the video plays) on a newer API level (tested on 16) but not on level 6.

```
    String FILEPATH = "/data/data/com.example.test1/videoname.flv";    

    //GET VIDEO FROM ASSETS
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("videoname.flv");

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FILEPATH);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[50000];
        int bytesRead;

        while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) !=-1){
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //SET VIDEO SOURCE AND PLAY VIDEO
    video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    video_player_view.setVideoPath(FILEPATH);
    video_player_view.start();
```

On API level 6, a message appears:

> "Sorry, this video cannot be played"

How can I play a video from the assets folder also in the very low API levels?

Comment: forget api < 7, http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @petey says, there's no need really to support anything below API 8. The bigger problem is that FLV was never supported natively and the support depended on the device and Flash plugin installation and the safest bet was to play the video in the WebView.

But since Google recently removed Flash plugin from the store and you can only install it manually from Adobe's website, you either need to stop using FLV or, money permitting, you should buy some of the player components that support the FLV format by themselves like Vitamio.